# React setting indexes of different lists on the same page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have two lists on a page, i am attempting to open only an item with the index of the item i have selected in a particular list but unfortunately, what i chose on list A also gets selected on list B onclick. I have named the indexes differently and the index as well but this keeps happening. My code is in the sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/tilegroup-test-forked-fp9zxb?file=/src/index.js) . Any assistance/advice on what i am doing wrong will be appreciated

```
 const recentVisits = [
    {
      id: '1',
      visit_type: 'Adult diabetes return visit',
      clinic: 'NCD clinic',
      visit_date: '2022-02-23T22:44:32.000+0000',
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      visit_type: 'Adult HIV return visit',
      clinic: 'HIV clinic',
      visit_date: '2022-02-23T22:44:32.000+0000',
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      visit_type: 'Adult HIV return visit',
      clinic: 'HIV clinic',
      visit_date: '2022-02-23T22:44:32.000+0000',
    },
  ];

  const futureVisits = [
    {
      id: '1',
      visit_type: 'Adult HIV return visit',
      clinic: 'HIV clinic',
      visit_date: '2022-02-23T22:44:32.000+0000',
    },
  ];

  const [recentVisitsIndex, setRecentVisitsIndex] = useState(0);
  const [show_priority, setShowPriority] = useState(false);
  const [futureVisitsIndex, setFutureVisitsIndex] = useState(0);
  const [prioritySwitcherValue, setPrioritySwitcherValue] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={styles.row}>
        <p className={styles.heading}> {recentVisits.length} visits scheduled for +/- 7 days </p>
        <TileGroup name="tile-group" defaultSelected="forever" className="trigger-tile">
          {recentVisits.map((visit, index) => (
            <RadioTile
              id={visit.id}
              value={visit.id}
              key={index}
              className={styles.visitTile}
              onClick={() => {
                setShowPriority(true);
                setRecentVisitsIndex(index);
              }}>
              <div className={styles.helperText}>
                <p>
                  index : {index} selectedindex : {recentVisitsIndex}
                </p>

                <p className={styles.primaryText}>{visit.visit_type}</p>
                <p className={styles.secondaryText}>
                  {visit?.visit_date} · {visit.clinic}
                </p>
                {show_priority && index == recentVisitsIndex ? (
                  <ContentSwitcher
                    size="sm"
                    className={styles.prioritySwitcher}
                    onChange={({ index }) => {
                      setPrioritySwitcherValue(index);
                    }}>
                    <Switch name={'Not Urgent'} text="Not Urgent" />
                    <Switch name={'Priority'} text="Priority" />
                    <Switch name={'Emergency'} text="Emergency" />
                  </ContentSwitcher>
                ) : null}
              </div>
            </RadioTile>
          ))}
        </TileGroup>
      </div>

      {/* List two */}

      <div className={styles.row}>
        <p className={styles.heading}> {futureVisits.length} visits scheduled for dates in the future </p>
        <TileGroup name="tile-group" defaultSelected="default-selected">
        {futureVisits.map((visit, ind) => (
          <RadioTile
            value={visit.id}
            key={ind}
            className={styles.visitTile}
            onClick={() => {
              setShowPriority(true);
              setFutureVisitsIndex(ind);
            }}>
            <div className={styles.helperText}>
              <p>
                index : {ind} selectedindex : {futureVisitsIndex}
              </p>
              <p className={styles.primaryText}>{visit.visit_type}</p>
              <p className={styles.secondaryText}>
                {visit?.visit_date} · {visit.clinic}
              </p>

              {show_priority && ind == futureVisitsIndex ? (
                <ContentSwitcher
                  size="sm"
                  className={styles.prioritySwitcher}
                  onChange={({ index }) => setPrioritySwitcherValue(index)}>
                  <Switch name={'Not Urgent'} text={'Not Urgent'} />
                  <Switch name={'Priority'} text={'Priority'} />
                  <Switch name={'Emergency'} text={'Emergency'} />
                </ContentSwitcher>
              ) : null}
            </div>
          </RadioTile>
        ))}
      </TileGroup>
      </div>

   </div>
  );
```

[image]

Comment: Please include relevant code as text in the question body itself. Also, your sandbox link is currently failing to build.

Answer (score 1):

You have an active recent visit, and an active future visit.

But both lists share the `show_priority` flag and the `prioritySwitcherValue` value. So you see the priority under the currently active recent and future visit.

The indexes do not clash, nor are they updated when you change one. But you do show the priority and set the `prioritySwitcherValue` for both active visits.

Comment: I will create different ```show_priority``` flag and ```prioritySwitcherValue``` flag for each list

Comment: @CKW this is a good example for when you should create a distinct component that can handle a single "list". And then just use that component twice, instead of creating double flag and setter functions for each scenario.